# Google search console says XML sitemap "can't fetch", yet sitemap passes test and is visible in browser

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, xml-sitemap

I've submitted a couple of sitemaps in search console but they are stuck on the 'cant fetch' status and have been for weeks now.

If I go to the URL I can see the sitemap OK and if I go to the old style search console and do test sitemap they all pass with no errors so I'm assuming Google can see them OK.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can get these to validate?

Here's an example link to one of my sitemaps:

`https://example.com/sitemaps/sitemap-pages.xml`

Comment: try adding your sitemap in your web root

Comment: The new sitemap report does show that error when in reality it is still processing the file. If the old one says fine, don't worry.

Comment: When I tried seeing a list of all your sitemaps, at https://quickplaysport.us/sitemaps/ I got a 403 Forbidden response. There's a chance that this block on the path from your root to your page is creating the crawler bottleneck. Try unblocking the sitemaps category page?

Comment: Thanks, when i go to the directory I get a 403 but if I go to the file URL then I see the xml file OK. I also added a copy of the sitemap into the root as suggested but this one does the same, its just stuck on couldn't fetch: https://quickplaysport.us/sitemap-pages.xml

Answer (score 1):

Context:

- I used `https://example.com/sitemaps.xml` and it got `couldn't fetch`.

Solution:

- Adding a suffix, e.g. `https://example.com/sitemaps.xml?sitemap=1`, works immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue with sitemaps generated by CMS at `/index.php?route=sitemap`.

Been getting the *Couldn't fetch* for the longest time. Waited for a while according to the most common advice. Didn't help.

What did help was making the sitemap available at `/sitemap.xml` and submitting that instead.

You can either rename the file if it's a static file, or create a rewrite rule for Apache/Nginx, e.g.:

```
rewrite ^/sitemap.xml$ /index.php?route=sitemap break;
```